# How to load dialog box automatically and dismiss in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I used 
`Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => welcomeDialogBoxx(context));`
in build, a method to load dialog box automatically but there is an issue with it, whenever I navigate through another screen the dialog box further open on that screen.
Dunno why it is loading further after got dismissed.

here is the method the defined for the dialog box

```dart
welcomeDialogBoxx(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            .....
          );
        });
  }
```

Comment: Why bother using a Dialog if you're going to automatically dismiss it after 0 second?

Comment: but there is an issue with it, whenever I go through the next page, the dialog box opens further. after it got popped it should not be open to another page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should open your dialog only once. Remove the Future from your Build method and add this code to your initState:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => welcomeDialogBox(context));
  }
```